# Some questions on division algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, brauer-groups

1. Given a field $K$, is there a finite dimensional quiver algebra, such that any finite dimensional division algebra is isomorphic to End(M)/rad(End(M)) for some indecomposable finite dimensional module M?
2. Can fields with finite Brauer group be somehow characterised?
3. What are the field with Brauer group equal to $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}3$? I do not even know one example. ($\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}3$ might be replaced by any finite abelian group with at least 3 elements)

Answer (score 10):

Questions 2 and 3 are addressed in section 11 of

*Auel, Asher; Brussel, Eric; Garibaldi, Skip; Vishne, Uzi*, [**Open problems on central simple algebras.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00031-011-9119-8), Transform. Groups 16, No. 1, 219-264 (2011). [ZBL1230.16016](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1230.16016).

In particular, the **Brumer-Rosen conjecture** implies that there are no fields with Brauer group $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ (and this is known), and only elementary abelian 2-groups appear. But this is still a conjecture, and $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$ isn't ruled out yet.

What I is very funny is that Ford has shown that every finite abelian group is the Brauer group of some *commutative ring*.

**Edit**: At the end of section 11 there is a reference to the very conveniently titled

*Efrat, Ido*, [**On fields with finite Brauer groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/pjm.1997.177.33), Pac. J. Math. 177, No.1, 33-46 (1997). [ZBL0868.12005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0868.12005).